# como realizar una vista la cual me arroje el tiempo de diferencia entre 2 fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

estaba realizando una vista pero no encuentro la forma de realizarla. Les muestro lo que tengo:

Tengo 3 tablas

tabla 1 `transaction_log`

[image: tabla 1]

tabla 2 `transfer`

[image: Tabla 2]

tabla 3 `estado`

[image: tabla 3]

realizo la siguiente vista:

```
select transaction_logs.transfer_id, transaction_logs.state_id,states.state,transaction_logs.created_at, transfers.branchDestiny_id,transfers.branchOrigin_id
from transaction_logs inner join transfers on transfers.id = transaction_logs.transfer_id inner join states on states.id= transaction_logs.state_id 
where transaction_logs.state_id in(3,6) and transfers.branchDestiny_id=4  order by transaction_logs.transfer_id desc;
```

Y me arroja este resultado:

[image: resultado de query]

El asunto es que, como ven, en `transfer_id` hay 2 iguales, pero el state es distinto y el `create_at` es distinto. El asunto es que quiero sacar la diferencia de tiempo de ver cuanto dura de pasar de state `"alisto realizado"` a `"Recibido"`, pero están en filas separadas. ¿Cómo podría, primeramente, unir los que tengan, por ejemplo, el `transfer_id` 4658 para que queden en una misma fila el los 2 `states` y los 2 `created_at`

este es un montaje de como quisiera que se viera la vista, el mismo transfer_id y sus respectivos states con su created_at
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa, sobre todo porque no usas los nombres reales de las tablas / columnas en el planteamiento. Parecería que necesitas agregar un `GROUP BY transfer_id`  y usar alguna función de cálculo para obtener la diferencia entre fechas.

Comment: voy a tratar de reformular la pregunta ya que me cuesta explicarla

Comment: ¿Qué versión de mysql utilizas?

Comment: ¿Los estados solo aparecen una vez para cada `transfer_id`? ¿Te interesan solo los que ya hayan pasado por los dos estados, o basta con que hayan pasado por el 3?

Comment: correcto ya que lo que manejo es como un log de eventos, entonces quiero poner los que tengan el mismo transfer_Id  en una columna el estado "alisto realizado", en otra columna el created_at, en otra columna el estado "recibido" y en la ultima columna el created_at

Comment: Revertí tu edicion. Por favor evita vandalizar tus publicaciones de ese modo... Que hayas encontrado la solución no hace que sea bueno alterar tu pregunta de manera que quede inservible. Otros podrían tener la misma duda que tu y recurriran a esta pregunta. Crees que la edición que hiciste hubiera ayudado a esas personas a entender el problema y saber si es el mismo que tienen ellos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes basar tu consulta en la tabla `transfers` y hacer `join` a la tabla `transaction_logs` dos veces, una para cada estado que te interesa.

Dado que quieres obtener también la descripción del estado, hay que hacer también 2 veces join a la tabla `states` una para cada estado.

Con esto, podemos obtener en columnas separadas el `created_at` de cada estado, así como su descripción, por ejemplo:

```
select   tranfers.transfer_id
       , st3.state state3
       , tl3.created_at created_at3
       , st6.state state6
       , tl6.created_at created_at6
       , transfers.branchDestiny_id
       , transfers.branchOrigin_id
  from transfers
       inner join transaction_logs tl3 on tl3.transfer_id = transfers.transfer_id and tl3.state_id = 3
       inner join states st3 on st3.id = tl3.state_id 
       inner join transaction_logs tl6 on tl6.transfer_id = transfers.transfer_id and tl6.state_id = 6
       inner join states st6 on st6.id = tl6.state_id 
 where transfers.branchDestiny_id = 4  
 order by transfers.transfer_id desc;
```

Comment: gracias colega!